# How do i disable git ident processing globally?

Tags: git, gitattributes

I'm trying to disable ident processing globally in a repo that contains legacy `.gitattributes` files that *enable* ident processing - I want to override that behavior without changing those files.

The gitattributes docs (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) seem to indicate that the `.git/info/attributes` file *should* take precedence:

> When deciding what attributes are assigned to a path, Git consults $GIT_DIR/info/attributes file (which has the highest precedence)

So, in this file I have put:

```
* -ident
```

which I believe *should* disable ident with highest precedence. (I have also tried `!ident`, but that doesn't work either)

However, ident processing is still occurring in my repo. Why, or more importantly: how do i do what i want?

I'm running git v2.18.2

Comment: There's something wrong with your `.gitattributes` file. The usual mistake is using Notepad's default of UTF-16-coded text, never a good idea. Save as plain ascii.

Comment: @jthill nope, i'm using linux. everything is LF-terminated.

Comment: `!ident` certainly *should* work as that turns the value back to unspecified. `-ident` turns it to unset, which probably should work too. You might build a version of Git and put some debug into `attr.c` to see what's going on here.

Comment: [`git check-attr ident *`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr)

Comment: The thing is, this doesn't happen for me.